# Breaking out from PLINQ Select Block (C#)

Tags: c#, plinq

Is there any way to break out form the SELECT block of the PLINQ ? Based on a condition within the SELECT block, I want to break the loop. So far I see various examples of using Cancellation token to break a PLINQ from outside the loop. But, my problem is to break from inside the loop.

Here is my code:

```
           var simulationResults =
                Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)
                    .AsParallel()
                    .WithCancellation(token ?? CancellationToken.None)
                    .Select(z =>
                    {
                        progressAction?.Invoke();

                        double aResult = someMethod()

                        if (double.IsNaN(aResult))
                        {
                            // todo: Find a way to Break the Parallel loop.
                        }

                        return aResult;
                    });
```

If there is No technique available, maybe I would need to find a hard way, like using a boolean flag with volatile keyword. I will set that flag with lock statement, within the PLINQ Select block and then next time, it will read that flag and determine if it should break. But, not sure if that will be a good solution. Moreover, I am highly reluctant to use lock inside PLINQ, which can defy the purpose of Parallel computing. Using Lock, I may enforce synchronization and not get the benefit of Parallel programming.

So any better idea ?

Comment: May be add `.TakeWhile(result => !double.IsNaN(result))` after the `Select`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Parallel.For` instead of `PLINQ`:

> Why not PLINQ?
>
> Even though PLINQ provides support for exiting from
>   within a query execution, the differences between PLINQ’s  exit
>   mechanism and Parallel.ForEach are substantial. To exit from a PLINQ
>   query, supply the query with a  cancellation token, as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460707(VS.100).aspx).
>   With Parallel.ForEach, exiting flags are polled on every iteration. In
>   PLINQ, the cancellation token is polled once every so often, so you
>   cannot assume that a cancelled query will stop  quickly.

Taken from **Exiting from Operations** section in [When To Use Parallel.ForEach and When to Use PLINQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/21/when-to-use-parallel-foreach-and-when-to-use-plinq/).

In the article above you can find detailed explanations how to stop a `Parallel.ForEach`/`Parallel.For` using `Stop` or `Break` methods of `ParallelLoopState` which are fully described there and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721(v=vs.110).aspx):

> In this context, "break" means complete all iterations on all threads
>   that are prior to the current iteration on the current thread, and
>   then exit the loop. "Stop" means to stop all iterations as soon as
>   convenient.

Using `Parallel.For` your code should be something like this:

```
var simulationResults = new ConcurrentBag<double>();
Parallel.For(0, 10000, (i, loopState) =>
{
    //I assume this method is thread safe
    progressAction?.Invoke();
    double aResult = someMethod()
    if (double.IsNaN(aResult))
    {
        //or loopState.Break();
        loopState.Stop();
    }
    simulationResults.Add(aResult);
});
```

One downside of using `Parallel.For` instead of `PLINQ` is when you need to preserve the input data order.
With `PLINQ` you can do it easily using [`AsOrdered`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413357(v=vs.110).aspx) method while with `Parallel.For` is much harder (but still possible, refer to the linked article for details).
But you didn't mention this requirement so I ignored it in the provided code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break at the first one not being a number, use `TakeWhile`. If you just want to skip them, you could use `Where`.

```
       var simulationResults =
            Enumerable.Range(0, 10000)
                .AsParallel()
                .WithCancellation(token ?? CancellationToken.None)
                .Select(z =>
                {
                    progressAction?.Invoke();
                    return someMethod();
                })
                .TakeWhile(result => !double.IsNaN(result));
```

Comment: Thanks, did not realize that the solution was so simple.